# Codeigniter PHP - Redirect giving internal server error on real server

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

- I have a default controller (pages) that redirects the pages to home
  (code below).

  - If I echo something just before the redirect it works.
  - If I echo anything in the home controller doesn't show anything which
    leads me to think that it doesn't reach the home controller.
  - If I replace the redirect with the code in the home controller it
    works fine.
  - The code works fine on localhost but always gives internal server
    error on the server.
  - If I load the templates instead of the redirect it works fine.

Adding 
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
Doesn't print anything.

Don't have access to the apache logs.

Pages controller:

```
<?php

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'index')
    {

        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        redirect('home', 'refresh');

    }
}
?>
```

Got a .htacces file with the following I tried to remove what was inside it still didn't work but i will put here anyway:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /site/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(application/views/templates/*/css|js|images/)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://example.com"
```

My base url in the config is configured to the site url like

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';
```

Don't know what else to do, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you try setting the base_url to empty? And can you confirm that you have mod_rewrite enabled on your server?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Using base_url as empty doesn't change anything. About the mod_rewrite that's a very nice tip didn't remember that locally i had to enable it. The apache configurations that I have access I can't see but i submitted a request to the hosting service to check it.

Comment: Hi, I got feedback from the hosting service, mod_rewrite is enabled by default on every host and they did test and it redirected correctly so the we can rule that out.

Comment: Hmm. And it's all working fine locally?

Comment: Yes. Works completly fine locally. :/

Comment: Found out the problem, thanks for your help Jeremy and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a few days finally I found out the problem, kind of a stupid error, works fine if in the .htaccess file I replace the

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

For

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Only the dot behind /index.php was causing the problem.
Locally worked fine but in the server..

Thanks Jeremy for your help.